# The way to convert from external url SVG image to base64 - js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, svg

**THIS WORKS WITH CASE WHEN WE WANT TO ADD SVG FIL To PDF FILE WITH jsPDF**

I spend a lot of time to find solution to add external svg file to generated PDF file with [jsPDF](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-svg.html#%7EaddSvg) package. Here is an example below. External svg file, simply a image which you get by url from some external server.

```
/**
 * @params url - for this case i am considering for example 'https//www.enter-external-url-link-here.svg';
 */

const convertSvgToBase64 = (url: string | null): string => {
  if (!url) {
    return '';
  }
  let result = null as string | ArrayBuffer | null;

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      // targeting existing img tag
      const img = document.getElementById('pdfCruiseLogo');
      if (reader.result) {
      // replacing src value with new value
        img?.setAttribute('src', reader.result.toString());
      // sending result back to img tag to be able to see new src value in the DOM
        result = reader.result;
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();

  if (typeof result !== 'string') {
    return '';
  }

  return result;
};

convertSvgToBase64(url);


// this is how it looks img element
// in this case convertSvgToBase64 imported as a helper outside of the component
 <img
   id="pdfCruiseLogo"
   :src="convertSvgToBase64(voyageData.voyage.cruiseLineLogoUrl)"
   :alt="voyageData.voyage.cruiseLineName"
 />
```

Comment: You have a basic "return a result from an asynchronous call" issue, but also I don't see what sense it makes to convert SVG to base64; it's already plain text.

Comment: @Pointy maybe they want to increase its size by 1/3? Anyway, not sure why the OP starts off by yelling...

Comment: @Pointy my intension is to be able to add svg image to PDF file, which i get by url _(https://some-image/image.svg)_ from external source as TwicPic. Reason is jsPDF doesnt sets image for some reason.